# Submit both value and text of a dropdownlist in a form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I use MVC HTML Helper to render a Html DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentId, menuSelectList)
```

I put this `DropDownList` in an HTML form. When press the button Submit in this form, a HTML Form Data will be created and sent in POST request. This data will contain key name `ParentId` with key value is `DropDownList`'s selected value. How I can include `DropDownList`'s **selected text** in this data with key name is `ParentName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You could use an hidden "ParentName" input, and populate it with the selected text (javascript / jQuery) when an change event is fired on your combo (DropDownList).

2) Just get the value from the key after submit (in the POST action), it should be possible (db query, for example).

3) Build your `selectList` in a way that the key contains key AND value (separated by a `~` for example, and split the "key~value" in the POST action)

I would personnaly go for second solution, but...

Comment: your meaning in the second solution: we can get key value by key name in controller but it takes time when calling to database?

Comment: @LuLu well yes, of course. But I don't think one (more) query will kill your app ;) Anyway, all solutions will work, so... You're free !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JavaScript, as the browser is not sending the selected text anywhere.

One trick is placing such code in the very bottom of your .aspx page: (before the `</body>`)

```
var arrDDLs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (var i = 0; i < arrDDLs.length; i++) {
    var oDDL = arrDDLs[i];
    if (!oDDL.name || oDDL.name.length === 0)
        continue;
    var inputName = oDDL.name + "_text";
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = inputName;
    input.id = inputName;
    oDDL.form.appendChild(input);
    oDDL.onchange = function () {
        var index = this.selectedIndex;
        var text = (index >= 0) ? this.options[index].text : "";
        var inputName = this.name + "_text";
        var input = document.getElementById(inputName);
        input.value = text;
    };

    //populate initial text:
    oDDL.onchange();
}
```

This code is essentially implementing the first idea in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355404/447356) and to take the selected text you just have to read Request value of the select key plus "_text" e.g.:

```
string selectedText = Request.Form[m.ParentId + "_text"];
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Kv8ky/). (JavaScript side only)